# argparse: How to make mutually exclusive arguments optional?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to use my script like this:

```
python test.py run
python test.py stop
```

and my code is like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
command_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
command_group.add_argument('run', help='run it', action='store_true')
command_group.add_argument('stop', help='stop it', action='store_true')
```

when I execute it, an exception is raised:

```
ValueError: mutually exclusive arguments must be optional
```

so I try to add `required=False` when I add each argument.Then I get another exception:

```
TypeError: 'required' is an invalid argument for positionals
```

I'm confused.

Comment: Why use a mutex group instead of [`choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#choices)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A better way to do this is to add a single positional argument that can have two choices.  Since you want it to be optional, use `nargs='?'`, which means zero or one times:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('run', help='run or stop', nargs='?', choices=('run', 'stop'))
```

If `run` is given, the value will be `'run'`.  If `stop` is given, it will be `'stop'`.  If neither is given, it will be `None`.

---

If you really want to use a mutually-exclusive group, I'm not sure if you can do it exactly how you want.  You *can*, however, make them optional arguments by adding a hyphen:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
command_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
command_group.add_argument('-run', help='run it', action='store_true')
command_group.add_argument('-stop', help='stop it', action='store_true')
```

Of course the problem with that is that the user also needs to provide the hyphen, but that's the sort of problem you can expect if you limit yourself like that.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But how should I write the code if I really want to use a mutex group?

Comment: @huron: I'm not sure you can.  See my edited answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve this with `nargs='?'`

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
command_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
command_group.add_argument('run', help='run it', nargs='?')
command_group.add_argument('stop', help='stop it', nargs='?')
```

Which would allow you to call the program with

```
python test.py run
```

or

```
python test.py stop
```

but **not**

```
python test.py run stop
```

Comment: This does not work. In Python 3 this results in a `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nargs'` error.

Comment: @herrbischoff: which version of python3 did you try this with? Even with the most recent version of python (3.8.3), I can get this to run.

Comment: I was experiencing the same problem as @herrbischoff and my problem turned out to be that my statement had a `action='store_true'` in it. as soon as that was removed, it no longer choked on the `nargs='?'`, edit for completeness: on version 3.8.2

Comment: You can't do this with `nargs`. `nargs` defines how many arguments AFTER your key word get consumed by that keyword. E.g. if you have `--file` you could allow to give you more than one file that you will work with. Then you use `nargs=+` (one or more). Your version here `nargs=?` consumes zero or one argument following your named one.

Comment: This example isn't correct. First, "run" and "stop" are just the names for your arguments, not the actual commands which you type. The arguments are **positional**, which means that the order defines which is which. And that is the problem: how should the parser understand which argument you mean? Mutual exclusive works for optional arguments (with --names), but not for positional ones.